# R Debugging Issue - Code not working

Tags: r

Hi Im having issues with the following code:

```
RepLetter(n) <- function(){
    return(rep(letters[7]))
}
```

I want to create a function that returns the nth letter of the alphabet n times.

For example I would want `"c"` repeated like `"c", "c", "c"`

So I could type `RepLetter(5)` and R would return `"e", "e", "e", "e", "e"`

Comment: `rep_letter <- function(i){rep(letters[i], i)}`, but you should really improve your title.

Comment: Apart from the function template error as answered, your function always tries to return a 1x repetition of `letters[7]` which is `"g"`. FYI, if you want a single string like this look at `strrep`.

Answer (score 2):

You have your function argument in the wrong place, and your arguments to `rep` are off.

```
Try this: 

RepLetter <- function(n){
  return(rep(letters[n],n))
}
```